# Lg ls840 phone says security error

Tags: lg

After rooting my lg LS840 I wanted to get rid of bloatware it was working fine till I restarted but now my phone wont boot it just says security error.

I already spent hours trying to fix using lg support tool but keeps hanging tried on two different computers I also goolgled how to return to factory but coudn't find anything that worked

Comment: Can you get to recovery or bootloader?

Comment: Can you also post an image of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instuctions I found

> Directions - Please read them carefully
>
> 1. Please make sure you have your LG Drivers installed before you start this process
>      you can go to Lg site to get current usb drivers
> 2. Please download one of these zip files from this links below
>
>    LS840ZVC https://www.dropbox.com/s/j63hoo0jsocid8y/LGVIPER.zip
>
>    LS840ZVD https://www.dropbox.com/s/3timbamztkewkdh/LS840ZVD.zip
> 3. Unzip and place the LG folder in C: root directory
> 4. Please have at least 60 percent battery or more and put the phone in download mode.
>
> You can do that by Plugging the usb cord while hold vol up and power.  Keep holding it until you see a screen that says downloading in progress.
>
> 5. Now go to your device manager and look for your com ports and find your LGE Android USB Serial Port.(not modems) Now double click it and look for advance and then click it. now we have too change the com port to 41. press ok and close it out.
> 6. Unplug your usb connection from phone and leave phone in download mode.
> 7. Now open your windows explorer go to C:\LG\LGFLASHTOOL\LGFlashTool.exe run as admin.
> 8. Model config will open select manual mode assign LS840...dll for dll and .tot for s/w.
> 9. Go to port settings and select port 1 only.
> 10. Now plug your usb cable back into the phone.
> 11. start the flash by pressing the arrow on the top left side and let it run
>
> --> !! Please don't let your desktop or laptop cutoff during the process. Please do not remove phone from usb cable until after the first reboot complete.
>
> It doesn't matter what percent your LG FlashTool is showing and you can close out LG FlashTool at that point. do a factory reset after you get too your home screen for the first time. now you device is ready too be used.
>
> don't forget to update profile on phone after it reloads

[Source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-viper-4g-lte/216964-factory-images-restore-your-phone-back-factory-unbrick-your-phone-print.html)

Comment: here is the link to the actual forum where I found it http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-viper-4g-lte/216964-factory-images-restore-your-phone-back-factory-unbrick-your-phone.html